# Get as many combinations of player matches for a tournament

Tags: python

I have the following arrays:

```
Group1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

Group2 = [i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]

Group3 = [q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x]
```

I want to create as many combinations as possible with 12 attempts.

To make it clearer: this is supposed to simulate matches in a tournament. 24 Total players facing off in 12 FFA matches of 8 players. I want each contestant to meet as many other contestants as possible. What is the best way to arrange this?

Comment: Is this an assignment in Algorithms? Did you try to solve it?

Comment: Its not an assignment. I want to get a solution for a friend of mine. I thought about it for a while but i just have no diea how to even begin solving this.

Comment: "for a friend" aye

Comment: yup, a brother to be more specific

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 9 more arrays with 8 characters each, for a total of 12 matches( the first 3 are obvious)